# Restrict access to URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, cancan

I am working with Ruby on Rails and trying to lock down a URL and nested URLs.  I have a URL that is accessed this way:

/profile/:id

I was able to simply lock down this URL by adding a check in the show action.  However, I need it to be a bit more robust.  I also need it to restrict access to other actions on this controller that are nested under the profile.  For example:

profile/:id/location
profile/:id/bio

I am using CanCan and have everything restricted as I had hoped.  However, I am now trying to allow access to profiles that are allowed.  Unfortunately, I only get the error "You are not authorized to access this page."  I have reviewed docs, tutorials and a RailsCast, but unfortunately I can't get it working.

In my controller:

```
@clients_purchasers = ClientsPurchasers.where(client_id: user.client.id,   
                          purchaser_id: @purchaser.id, profile_status: "active")
authorize! :show, @clients_purchasers
```

I tried to figure out how to set up my ability.rb file but I am not 100% certain on how to do this.

My ability.rb file I believe is the disconnect.  Here is what I have:

```
 if user.role.name == "Manager"
   can :read, ClientsPurchasers
 end
```

Adding this still restricts access to the profile.  I have also tried passing parameters to restrict access to ClientsPurchasers that should not be viewable:

`can :read, ClientsPurchasers, :profile_status => "active", client_id: user.client.id`

All of these didn't help.

Comment: If you have CanCan running, you would do well to post your `ability.rb` file, since whatever rules are there might be what's blocking access. I also assume you're actually using CanCanCan and not CanCan.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I have updated my question with the ability.rb file information.  I am actually using CanCan and not CanCanCan.